# Building a tridiagonalsolver

Tags: r

Was given a task to code a tridiagonal solver.
 However when i try to run the solver, i get no results.
 I can't find my error in the code and would appreciate any help that i can get.

```
a<-cbind(-1,-1,-1)
b<-cbind(2.04,2.04,2.04,2.04)
c<-cbind(-1,-1,-1) 
d<-c(40.8,0.8,0.8,200)

tridiagsolver<-function(a,b,c,d){
 N<-length(b)
 for (n in (2:N)){
 ratio<-a[n]/b[n-1]
 b[n]=b[n]-ratio*c[n-1]
 d[n]=d[n]-ratio*d[n-1]
 }
  d[N]=d[N]/b[N]
  for (n in (1:(N-1))){
   d[N-n]=(d[N-n]-c[N-n]*d[N-n+1])/b[N-n]
  }
  return(d)
  }
tridiagsolver(a,b,c,d)
> tridiagsolver(a,b,c,d)
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: `a[N]` is not defined, since `b` is longer than `a`.

Comment: Indexing problem? For example, `a[n]/b[n-1]` will eventually give `NA` for `n = 4`.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, that helped and i've gotten my results =)